# ui.router and multiple views not working

Tags: angularjs

I just dont get ui.router and why my views will not show. I go to /manageservices abd I get nothing despite content in left and right html.

I my page where I want to show a left and right view.

```
<!--/manageservices.html-->
<div ng-controller="ManageServicesCtrl">
    <div ui-view="left"></div>
    <div ui-view="right"></div>
</div>

 <!--/left.html-->
<div ng-controller="ManageServicesCtrl">
left
</div>

<!--/right.html-->
<div ng-controller="ManageServicesCtrl">
right
</div>
```

My config file:

```
ms.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {     
    $stateProvider
    .state('manageservices', {
        url: "/manageservices",
        templateUrl: 'static/app/manage-services/manageservices.html',
        controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl',
        views: {
          'left':  {
            templateUrl: 'static/app/manage-services/left.html',
            controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl'
          },
          'right': {
            templateUrl: 'static/app/manage-services/right.html',
            controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl'
          }
        }//end views 
    })

})
```

Below is firebug.  I am getting 200 on both pages but the content is not showing.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/app/manage-services/right.html

304 NOT MODIFIED
        192ms   
angular.min.js (line 93)

GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/app/manage-services/left.html

304 NOT MODIFIED
        192ms   
angular.min.js (line 93)




Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'manageservices'
v/y.transitionTo@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:16913
v/y.go@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:16389
D/<.link/</e<@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:24861
f/m<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:146:220
e@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:43:93
Kf/l.defer/c<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:45:491

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js
Line 107
```

Comment: As far as i see you have only 2 sub views *left* and *right* without content? Can you provide a plunker?  Btw you do initialize the `ManagedServicesCtrl` twice. Once in the configuration and once in the html.

Comment: Hi I updated by code how i actually have it and added the left and right html

Comment: Can you add your index html? Do you get any errors? What actually loads when you inspect?

Comment: I see in firebug the pages are loaded.  Added to question. But the content is not showing on the page.

Comment: Am i not making left and right children on manageservices.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Views override state's template properties](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#views-override-states-template-properties)
>
> If you define a views object, your state's templateUrl, template and
>   templateProvider will be ignored. So in the case that you need a
>   parent layout of these views, you can define an abstract state that
>   contains a template, and a child state under the layout state that
>   contains the 'views' object.

You need to create an abstract parent. See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KKelWQkULTjEpENC12rU?p=preview)

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("manageservices");
  $stateProvider
    .state('manageservices', {
      abstract : true,
      templateUrl: 'managedservices.html',
      controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl'
    })
    .state('manageservices.main', {
      url: "/manageservices",
      views: {
        'left': {
          templateUrl: 'left.html',
          controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl'
        },
        'right': {
          templateUrl: 'right.html',
          controller: 'ManageServicesCtrl'
        }
      } //end views 

    })
```

PS. remove the `ng-controller="ManageServicesCtrl"` from the HTML. You already defined the controller in the configuration!

Comment: Thanks much.  I do this get this error though.  Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'manageservices'  full is placed in question.

Comment: How do you navigate? Links or javascript? Probalby you have to reference the sub state. try `$state.go('manageservices.main');` or `<a ui-sref="manageservices.main">State 1</a>`

Comment: Hi I did this and it worked. href="/#/manageservices".  I dont understand why.

Comment: but I added ui-sref="manageservices.main" and worked well.  Thanks very much for your help! Learned lot.